# Windows phone 8.1 App runs in emulator but on device gets hung on splash screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a windows phone 8.1 runtime app that will run perfectly on the emulators, but when i try to deploy to my device the app will not go past the splash screen. 
When I step through the debugger it stops on the following:

```
// Ensure the current window is active
Window.Current.Activate();
```

Comment: Aaaand when you don't do that, what happens?

Comment: stops on the splash screen

Comment: You shouldn't need to call that.  As for the application stopping on the splash screen, nah.  Something else is going on. What is it? Who knows.  Go to the code after the splash and halt execution there.  If it doesn't hang, move down the code path a bit.  Find out what code is hanging.